# generate array from start and end string

Tags: php, arrays

I am sorry to ask simple question.

```
function generateArray( $start, $end)
{

 //do task
 return $arr
} 

example 

$start= '47_000008';
$end= '47_000011'

$arr= generateArray( $start, $end);
```

here element of array should be

```
arr[0]=47_000008'
arr[1]=47_000009'
arr[2]=47_000010'
arr[3]=47_000011'
```

i need a help to write the function

here, start and end value can be between 47_000001 to 47_999999

Thanks

Comment: Will the function need to work with `48_` as well? With `49_`?

Comment: what will be the value of $start & $end parameter

Comment: here, start and end value can be between 47_000001 to 47_999999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my version for leading null

```
    function generateArray( $start, $end)
    {
        $startArray=explode("_",$start);
        $endArray=explode("_",$end);
        $arr=array();
        if(count($startArray)==2)
        {
            $laenge=strlen($startArray[1]);
            $startInt=(int)$startArray[1];
            $endInt=(int)$endArray[1];
            for($i=$startInt;$i<=$endInt;$i++)
            {
                $arrString=""+$i;
                while(strlen($arrString)!=$laenge)
                    $arrString="0".$arrString;
                $arr[]=$startArray[0]."_".$arrString;
            }
        }
        return $arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your string format is XX_XXXXX. First of all split the string into array, like

```
$startList = explode("_",$start);
$endList = explode("_",$end);
```

Now run a for loop to increment the last value of the start array and push it to a result array, like

```
$totalindex = $endList[1]-$startList[1];
$startvalue=$startList[1];
for($i=0;$i<$totalindex;$i++){
   $startvalue=$startvalue+$i;
   $newArray[$i]=$startList[0]."_".$startvalue;
}
```

Consider the error validation.

Comment: thanks for your response. it returning 47_8, 47_9, 47_10, 47_11 as out out. i need 6 digit after '_'